# Word-order in indirect questions

Tags: word-order

I'm taught that in indirect questions   the verb   comes after the subject:

> Do you know what time the bank opens?

But what if  the question proper goes first? Should one say

> What time the bank opens is an interesting question

or

> What time does the bank open is an interesting question?

Comment: It matters not whether the embedded question is preposed or follows the matrix verb. In both constructions there should be no inversion.

Comment: You have green-ticked a wrong answer. These are embedded questions and hence there should be no inversion.

Comment: But that's exactly what the author says: "

    What time the bank opens is an interesting question.

is correct"

Comment: Yes, it is correct, but the point is that "what time the bank opens" is an embedded question and that is why there should be no inversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first version

> What time the bank opens is an interesting question.

is *correct* because '*What time the bank opens*' is a *nominal clause* which functions as the *subject* of the verb *is*.

https://www.englishgrammar.org/relative-pronoun/

To turn the question '*What time does the bank open?*' into subject, it is possible to use quotation marks:

> "What time does the bank open?" is an interesting question.

It is rarely used phraseology, but here's another example where quoted questions function as noun phrases:

*The Dream Questionnaire items included “How often do you remember your dreams?” and “What do you most often dream about?”* http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/08/punctuating-around-quotation-marks.html

Comment: "What time the bank open" is not a nominal clause. It's a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question), and since it is subordinate, no inversion is required. You've omitted the two most important factors!

Answer (score 1):

> [1] *Do you know* [*what time the bank opens*]?
>
> [2] [*What time the bank opens*] *is an interesting question*.

In both examples, the bracketed constituent is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question).

It matters not whether the embedded question is complement of a verb, as in [1], or subject of the sentence. In both constructions there should be no inversion.

The meaning of [1] is:

*"Do you know the answer to the question 'What time does the bank open?'"*

And the meaning of [2] is:

*"The answer to the question 'What time does the bank open?' is an 
interesting question".*